# Break Line in a table

Tags: tables

I would like to know how to break line in a table so the text stays the same width as the rest of the text. My code is:

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Precision variation.}
\centering
\label{tab1}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Work & Year & Blockchain Funcionality & Pros & Cons \\
\hline
\cite{song2019} & 2019 & Digital signature storage & Authenticated information & Centralized architecture \\
\cite{shang2018} & 2018 & Information storage & Scratch Information & Unauthenticated information \\
\cite{huckle} & 2017 & Hash/metadata storage & Authenticated information & High cost \\
Our Work & 2019 & Algorithm processing & Reliability e Authenticity & None \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

My output is:

[image]

As can be seen, the table exceeds the text with limit. How do i solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead column's type `c` you should use ones, which enable to break text in more line. For example `p{<width>}` or `\m{<width>}` from `array` package, `X` from `tabularx` package:

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Precision variation.}
\label{tab1}
    \centering
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|c|*{3}{C|}}
\hline
Work & Year & Blockchain Funcionality & Pros & Cons \\
\hline
\cite{song2019} & 2019 & Digital signature storage & Authenticated information & Centralized architecture \\
\cite{shang2018}& 2018 & Information storage & Scratch Information & Unauthenticated information \\
\cite{huckle}   & 2017 & Hash/metadata storage & Authenticated information & High cost \\
\makecell[t]{Our\\ Work}
                & 2019 & Algorithm processing & Reliability e Authenticity & None \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
or

\begin{table}
\caption{Precision variation.}
\label{tab2}
    \centering
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} cc *{3}{L} @{} }
    \toprule
Work & Year & Blockchain Funcionality & Pros    & Cons      \\
    \midrule
\cite{song2019} & 2019 & Digital signature storage & Authenticated information & Centralized architecture \\
\cite{shang2018}& 2018 & Information storage & Scratch Information & Unauthenticated information \\
\cite{huckle}   & 2017 & Hash/metadata storage & Authenticated information & High cost \\
\makecell[t]{Our\\ Work}
                & 2019 & Algorithm processing & Reliability e Authenticity & None \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]